# Using QT and VS run CGAL5.2's official examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, cgal

I downloaded the official example which is `CGAL-5.2\examples\Triangulation_2` from the website [CGAL.org](https://www.cgal.org/).
I successfully cmake the examples.
Then I opened `Triangulation_2_Examples.sln` from  `G:\MyCGAL_code\code_1\Triangulation_2\build` by VS2017.
I also successfully built all projects (without errors).
I then click the debugger in VS: the `draw triangulation.exe` running fine, but the `Triangulation_2 Basic_viewer` is empty.
I knew someone's successful results has colored triangles in the window called `Triangulation_2 Basic_viewer`.
Did anyone try this official example before?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program `draw_triangulation_2` takes a filename as input (the file must contains a set of 2D points).

Without parameter, it takes `data/triangulation_prog1.cin` by default.

Thus the working directory must contains a directory data and this directory must contains a file `triangulation_prog1.cin`. Otherwise, the triangulation is empty.

To solve your problem, you need either to create the data directory and copy `triangulation_prog1.cin` in this directory; or give a valid filename as parameter.

Comment: thank you very much , i copy the file "data" into the file "build" , the "data" file contain some files which included some "CIN" files ,so the program can find theses inputs. It works!

Comment: but do you know how to generate such "CIN" files?  can it be generated by some software? Photoshop?

Comment: Have a look to the content of data/triangulation_prog1.cin !
The format is very simple: a sequence of 2D points, one per line.